# denoising floor function

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, noise, signal-detection, denoising

Suppose that

$y(t) = \lfloor x(t) + \epsilon(t) \rfloor$,

where $\epsilon(t)$ is zero mean, independent noise.

Is there any techniques on recovering $x(t)$ from $y(t)$?

Comment: I assume $\epsilon$ is of limited variance (i.e. power), and $x(t)$ is at least weak-sense stationary/has an autocorrelation function about which you know something, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bit more complicated that mere denoising, since a highly non-linear operator affects the original signal. Restoration or recovery would be more appropriate.

The floor function acts as an instance of data **quantization** (and possibly **saturation** or **clipping**). And adding noise is also known as [**dithering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither), a method to  reduce sensitive quantization effects (**dequantization**).
Those are keywords you can use along with: restoration, recovery, inference... Without more information on the signal's dynamics, models, and the noise, a couple of pointers that I am aware of (to be updated):

- [Wavelet denoising of coarsely quantized signals](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIM.2006.873790)
- quantized compressing sensing
- piecewise regular approximations